# How to use the checkbox:checked attribute properly in CSS?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm having a little problem with the well known CSS checkbox trick.
I am trying to make a responsive nav bar.

I have used it before, and it worked before, but now even if I copy the old code that worked before, now it just simply doesnt work.

Here is the code I have made:

```css
.hamburger {
  width: 35px;
  height: 40px;
}

.responsive-nav-div {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.responsive-nav~.responsive-nav-div {
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav-div">
  <div class="nav-div-1">
    <ul class="nav-ul">
      <li class="nav-li"><a class="nav-a" href="index.php">HOMEPAGE<a/></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-div-2">
            <ul class="nav-ul-2">
                <li class="nav-li"><a class="nav-login-register" href="login.php">LOGIN<a/></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="responsive-nav-main-div">
        <label for="responsive-nav" class="responsive-nav-label"><img  class="hamburger" src="images/hamburger2.png" alt="Responsive-NAV"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="responsive-nav" class="responsive-nav">
        <div class="responsive-nav-div">
            <ul class="responsive-nav-ul">
                <li class="responsive-li2"><a class="responsive-a2" href="index.php">HOMEPAGE<a/></li>
                <li class="responsive-li2"><a class="responsive-a2" href="login.php">LOGIN<a/></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I click on the checkbox or the hamburger icon (the label), it just simply doesnt apply `left: 0px;`. And this is so annoying, im trying to get this to work for like 3 hours now, what am I missing?

And before you ask, yes I have cleared the web browser cache just in case.

I don't really intend to use javascript for that hack that worked before, so please dont suggest javascript!

Any help related to the `:checked` attribute would be helpful, thanks :D!

Comment: You forgot to set `:checked`. Try like this - `.responsive-nav:checked ~ .responsive-nav-div{}`

Comment: whoops, now I forgot that, but I had it before like that,now I added `:checked` but still it doesnt toggle anything, I even tried to change a background color of something else, just to see if it works, but nothing.

Comment: Cannot really reproduce the problem. In the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ku3whfe9/1/) everything seems working

Comment: wow, thats interesting, is it possible that something else affects the code? Is the order of CSS codes matter anything?

Comment: I cant believe this, I have deleted the nav bar (the not responsive one) and now it toggles the links, so looks like it is something to do with the other nav. Thanks mate :D!

Comment: Okay, the problem is still not solved, because the trick only works if I delete the two ˙<li> and <a>`s, I tried to delete the classes, to see if it conflicts, but no it just still doesnt toggle it on or off, could you take a look at it? I will update the post so you can see it

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example? Like adding the classes/elements that you think are conflicting?

Comment: So you mean, could I make the same problem again? I dont think so, I tried deleting all the classes if that conflicts it but nothing.

Comment: Well, the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tLj9b81z/) is still working. Even with additional code you just provided

Comment: Okay, looks like I solved it, the problem was simply an html tag written wrong (because I am using notepad++, and just saw the problem in fiddle.
I wrote `<a/>` instead of `</a>` as closing to `<a>`, and thats it, thanks for help, appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

It has a simple typo that's why the CSS design is not working properly:

On this line you had

`<li class="nav-li"><a class="nav-login-register" href="login.php">LOGIN<a/></li>`

On the Part `LOGIN<a/></li>` has a typo of `</a>`

```css
.hamburger {
  width: 35px;
  height: 40px;
}

.responsive-nav-div {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.responsive-nav:checked ~ .responsive-nav-div{
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav-div">
  <div class="nav-div-1">
    <ul class="nav-ul">
      <li class="nav-li"><a class="nav-a" href="index.php">HOMEPAGE<a/></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-div-2">
            <ul class="nav-ul-2">
                <li class="nav-li"><a class="nav-login-register" href="login.php">LOGIN</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="responsive-nav-main-div">
        <label for="responsive-nav" class="responsive-nav-label"><img  class="hamburger" src="images/hamburger2.png" alt="Responsive-NAV"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="responsive-nav" class="responsive-nav">
        <div class="responsive-nav-div">
            <ul class="responsive-nav-ul">
                <li class="responsive-li2"><a class="responsive-a2" href="index.php">HOMEPAGE<a/></li>
                <li class="responsive-li2"><a class="responsive-a2" href="login.php">LOGIN<a/></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```